# Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter

Tags: cassandra

I backed up a production database (runs on many nodes) on my local machine (with sampled data).

when I recreated the database on my local dev box, I created it with simple strategy and 1 replica.

My application uses simple JDBC code using cassandra jdbc driver. When I start my application I see 100s of messages like

```
{
"msg":"Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for 
DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the
 correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy
constructor)
"},
"category":"com.datastax.driver.core.policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy",
"host":"foo.local",
"logger":"com.datastax.driver.core.policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy",
"thread":"main","level":"info"}

{
"msg":"New Cassandra host devbox/XX.XX.XX.XX:9042 added"},
"category":"com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster",
"host":"foo.local",
"logger":"com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster",
"thread":"main","level":"info"
}
```

I can easily connect to my database, query it. All tests run fine. Then I don't understand why I am getting these two message like 100s of times on startup.

edit: here is the output of `nodetool status`

```
objc[4506]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x105ad84c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x105ba04e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  2.46 MiB   256          100.0%            1bf6cbd8-22c1-42e5-afdd-c1846be9e322  rack1
```

Comment: Check the output of `nodetool status`